# button with image and text using canvas windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

hi i'm trying to customize a button. In the button i want to set some back ground image and on top of that image i want to draw some text. For that i'm adding that text on top of canvas and background for that canvas i am giving the image.

Everything is working fine but the image is getting cropped if i m giving same size like image is having for the button.

How i can make that image fit on  the button and also same size i am giving for the `canvas(image size)`?

```
Button button = new Button();
button.Width = 40;
button.Height = 40;
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.Width = 40;
canvas.Height = 40;
ImageBrush img = new ImageBrush();
img.ImageSource = some image
canvas.Background = img;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should play with the Margin of the Image to say -20. (or some negative value)

Try for e.g. img.Margin = new Thickness(-20);

canvas.Margin = new Thickeness(-10);
button.Content = canvas;